# Why does placing a Word document as input in a Web form launch the process WINWORD.EXE?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-word, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have IE 11 on Win 7 — yes, I live dangerously.

I have [a Web form, like this](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html).

I click *Browse...* and I choose a Word document. I don't even send the form.

The process WINWORD.EXE starts, and I get — twice — a stupid error message about Word unable to do whatever...

**Why does that happen ? What kind of intrusion is that ?**

It must be one “specialty” of IE on Window$. What is IE trying to do here ?

**Bonus question : How to get rid of this “feature” ?**

I have Office Pro Plus 2010, and my file has the suffix *.doc*.

Comment: What does the "stupid" message says, exactly?

Comment: What are you doing when you "choose a Word document"?  Are you double-clicking?  Confirming the dialog? Something else?

Comment: I just tested on Win 7, with IE11 and Office 2013 Standard. This doesn't happen for me.  Try it in Safe Mode with Networking, if it doesn't do it there, then you have a piece of software interfering.

Comment: @and31415 - The stupid error message is : *Word could not create the work file. Check the temp environment variable.*

Comment: Check this support article: ["Word could not create the work file" error message when you save a document in Word 2013, Word 2010 or in Office Word 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2285187/en-us)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause.

I tested with Firefox :

1. The process WINWORD.EXE does get briefly launched.
2. But, strangely, I don't get any error message.

**The cause of the behaviour is in the file choosing dialog, it is the preview pane on the right.**

When I remove the preview pane in the dialog before clicking on my file, the problem disappears. But when I change folder in the dialog, the preview pane comes back, this is annoying.